# react-latex fraction line doesn't display

Tags: reactjs, math, rendering, equation

I'm developing a React PWA using Latex to display math equations.  Most equations display perfectly, but the division line is missing in fractions. The component imports react-latex 1.6.0 and katex.min.css is cached.

The division line is missing in Chrome, Safari and Xcode simulator.

Here's the React/JSX code in a stateless functional component:

```
let a = 5;
let b = 6;
const fraction = `$$\\huge\\frac{${a}}{${b}} \\times \\frac{4}{11} = ?$$`;
<h3>
Multiply fractions:
</h3>   
<Latex displayMode={true}>{fraction}</Latex>
```

Output: 
[fraction display example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcw6o.png)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your output doesn't look very huge. I tried plugging your formula into the [online demo](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) at mathjax.org, and got results that were broken in a slightly different way. However, wrapping the whole LaTeX expression with a HTML `<div>` element containing a font-size style attribute looks like it might fix the issue. For example, try `<div style="font-size:55px">$$\huge{\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{4}{11} = ?}$$</div>`

Comment: My display example may have been misleading.  The huge attribute is working, but I'd actually just tried it since another thread suggested it solved the missing fraction division line problem.  I tried the \over syntax shown in the demo link you provided -- but same problem: horizontal division line doesn't display.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Problem solved: I didn't realize there was a newer version of katex.min.css.  I updated from version 0.9.0 to version 0.11.1 and it is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this in Discourse with the Maths plugin.
I had increased the browser Zoom.
When I returned the Zoom to 100 the lines appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and it worked in my case. paste this in you index.html file.
Here the `katex.min.css` version is `0.11.1` you might have `0.9.0`

```
<link
        href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.11.1/katex.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
    />
```